# How is it possible to delete Flyway migrations

Tags: java, database-migration, flyway

Colleagues! I have flyway files which have been already used in my project and I need to delete several of these files. Ex: I have files with versions V1.0.0.1,V1.0.0.2,V1.0.0.3,V1.0.0.4 and I need to delete the last two files. I found that the best practice is don't change that is already used...so, how can I do this?

Comment: You should not need to delete any migration scripts. The whole point of Flyway is to accumulate all the migration scripts over time. Flyway is responsible for knowing which scripts have already been run versus which need to be run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to not delete, instead you should consider that define undo both `1.0.0.3` and `1.0.0.4` in new migration, such as `1.0.0.5`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove your files and needed records from metadata table (schema_version).
But it's not good practice.

Comment: If I do that, the next file must consist the v1.0.0.5 version or v1.0.0.3?

Comment: next must be V1.0.0.3

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, deleting migration scripts would require changes to your schema history table which would not be recommended as Flyway migrations build on the ones previously applied and could cause confusion with what scripts have been run or not. If you are using the community version of Flyway, you will need to make new migration scripts which remove what was done in the migration scripts you wish to delete. If you have access to Flyway Teams, there's an [undo](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/undo) function which does do what it looks like you're trying to achieve.